# Why don't I get a confirmation email when I register?

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel 8.x and trying to get the built-in login/registration code to work properly on a new project. I don't have much prior experience with Laravel or its authentication code but if I recall correctly, when I register, I'm supposed to get a confirmation email that must be replied to for the registration to be fully successful. I'm not getting that confirmation email.

The users table has a row in it for both of the two IDs I've registered - both emails belonging to me - but neither email address has received a confirmation email after a substantial wait. I've also checked my junk/spam folders and verified that the confirmation email didn't go there. The rows in the users table have nulls in the "email_verified_at" and "remember_token" columns so I know that the registration did *something*, it just didn't send the confirmation emails. I haven't touched any of the modules involved in registration; in fact, I recreated them from scratch before attempting to register anything.

What do I have to do to coax Laravel to send the confirmation emails?

Comment: Why *don’t* you? Here are some possibilities: 1) “bad code” (that never sends the email); 2) bad email gateway/server (that fails to send the email); 3) incorrect email address (oops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Model

```
<?php

  namespace App;

  use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
  use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
  use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

  class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
  {
    use Notifiable;

    // ...
  }
```

> Route

```
 Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
```

Answer (score 1):

> "... verify that your `App\Models\User` model implements the `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail` contract"

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
...

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
```

> "Once this interface has been added to your model, newly registered users will automatically be sent an email containing an email verification link."

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Email Verification - Model Preparation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/verification#model-preparation)